# According to the Catholic Church, who was God talking to, at Babel?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, genesis, babel

At Genesis 11: 5-7 we read:

" The Lord came down to see the city and the tower, which mortals had built.  And the Lord said, “Look, they are one people, and they have all one language; and this is only the beginning of what they will do; nothing that they propose to do will now be impossible for them.  Come, let us go down, and confuse their language there, so that they will not understand one another’s speech.”

My question is: Who was/were God talking to, when He said "..let us go down.." ? Was it to the angels, or to the Holy Spirit ? What do the teachings of Catholic Church tell about the words of God at Babel ?